# TypeError: invokeMember GraalVM native-image

Tags: java, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying create a native-image with GraalVM, my code:

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.HostAccess;

public class Console {

    @HostAccess.Export
    public void print(String msg){
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Then I call the code itself like this one:

```
public void callMethod(CommonRequest request) throws ScriptException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        s.append(new PluginJS().load(request.getMethodPath(), true));

        Context context = null;
        try {
            context = Context.newBuilder()
                    .allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL)
                    .allowAllAccess(true)
                    .allowCreateThread(true)
                    .allowHostClassLoading(true)
                    .allowIO(true)
                    .allowNativeAccess(true)
                    .allowCreateProcess(true).build();

            putMembers(context.getBindings("js"));

            context.eval("js", s.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            context.close();

        }

    }

    private void putMembers(Value value) { 
        value.putMember("Console", new Console());


    }
```

It's work fine when I run through IDE or java -jar, but When I try compile to native-image throws an error. Bellow the error follow by the command-line used to compile native-image.

**Error**:

TypeError: invokeMember (print) on JavaObject[com.compiler.commons.log.Console@113a2d320 (com.compiler.commons.log.Console)] failed due to: Unknown identifier: print

**Command-line**

```
graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir=/Users/ze/Documents/java/tool/config compiler-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/bin/native-image --language:js --initialize-at-build-time nomeApp -jar compiler-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Please could someone help me?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've solved, I needed clean from "/config" files, execute the application along agent and then compile adding some different parameters. See both below:

**agent**

```
/Users/ze/Documents/programs/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-merge-dir=/Users/ze/Documents/gitprojects/java/tool/config ./target/compiler-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**compile**

```
sudo /Users/ze/Documents/programs/graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0/Contents/Home/bin/native-image --language:js --initialize-at-build-time -H:+AllowIncompleteClasspath -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=/Users/ze/Documents/gitprojects/java/tool/config nameOfApp -jar ./target/compiler-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```